# Combine .xls files from multiple folders into one data frame

Tags: r

I have 96 folders located in the directory ./data*/..
Some folders contain an .xls file and some do not. 
I would like to make a data frame where column number 6 from the files is the row names and a count how for each occurence.

Here is a start:

```
setwd("~/")
file_list = list.files(pattern="/data*/*.xls")   
library(data.table)
lst <- lapply(file_list, function(x) 
  fread(x, select=c("V6"))[, 
                                 list(ID=paste(V1)])
df <- as.data.frame(Reduce(function(x,y) x[y, on = "ID"], lst))
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: a script that looks for .xls files in the folder and combines columns from all the files.